# Fire updateprogress regardless of processing time

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, updateprogress

Is it possible to fire my `UpdateProgress` so I can get my loading animation to appear for a set amount of time even if the processing finishes faster?

I have a dropdown that changes the results in a table on selected index change and it is being processed too fast so it is hard for users to tell if anything has happened.

I want my loading gif to appear for half a second just to show something has happened.  Is this possible through the update panel control or do I have to write some javascript to do this?

Further to this I don't really want to be doing things on button click like:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

According [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.aspx):

> By default, the `UpdateProgress` control waits `.5` seconds (`500 milliseconds`) before it displays its contents. This helps prevent the control from flashing if an asynchronous postback is very quick. You can specify the delay by setting the `DisplayAfter` property.

So you can set this value to some other to set your `UpdateProgress` to appear faster. But I think this can't solve your issue, so try out this:

> If you need finer control over when an `UpdateProgress` control is displayed, you can provide client script for the [`beginRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432.aspx) and [`endRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx) events of the [`PageRequestManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx) class. In the `beginRequest` event handler, you can display the DOM element that represents the `UpdateProgress` control. In the `endRequest` event handler, you can hide it.

You can store a start date and time for your callback, and at the end of request just check this value.

Comment: I tried the displayafter and set it to zero but the loading gif only flashed up so if you blink you'd miss it.  Would be useful if there was a displayfor property!  Looks like the javascript route it is then unless anyone else can come up with another way